# How to add properties to tbody, td and tr in bootstrap table, using div and id

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to customize a Bootstrap table. I cannot add tbody{ } and tr{ } as there are multiple tables being used, hence it will affect all the tables. Also the table is within a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign id to the tables you want to modify and then add the CSS code!

Comment: What is the syntax to add the class ?? I have added the id to table already

Comment: you add class as <table class="class1">...</table> and in CSS it is defined as .class1 { //body }

Comment: class is basically like belonging to one group. So everybody in that group will have same properties. In case of <table> the properties of its children that is <tbody> <tr> and <td> will also have same properties as that of table!

Comment: Use different classes. Don't add all properties to global class. Add only those which are to be modified globally like font-size or font-family or color, etc. To just change the tr width use a seperate body for tr in css as .class1 tr { //body }

Comment: Can you please also tell me how to reduce the "row height" ?? Height or line-height does not work, instead the data formatter box in the row gets shrinked. How can I fix that ?

Comment: .class1 tr { height: 10px; } . Try this

Comment: it doesn't work, same thing happening, my data-formatter input box in the row get's shrinked, while row-height remains the same

Comment: I am not able to get what problem you are facing!

Comment: There was some padding issue, which was overriding, it is solved now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a table and give it an `id`:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed" id="YOUR_TABLE_ID">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Add css that applies only to the table per the `id` e.g.:

```
#YOUR_TABLE_ID {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#YOUR_TABLE_ID > tbody > tr > td {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-all;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```